# kafkastream not receiving any record after restart due to abrupt kill

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

My Stream was working fine, due to some reason  it was killed using command pkill,  now after restarting it is not working, it not receiving anything.

My Stream Consumer : Here I am configuring as 4 stream task,
// stream Consumer Handler

```
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> userStream = builder.stream("usertopic",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-userstream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ALL my bootstrap servers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "500");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        //consumer_timeout_ms
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 2000);

        props.put("state.dir","/tmp/kafka/stat));


   userStream.peek((key,value)->System.out.println("key :"+key+" value :"+value));
   /* pass  stream to my logic commented */

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);


kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

                logger.error("Thread Name :" + t.getName() + " Error while processing:", e);
            }
        });


        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
```

Stream starting logs:

```
:43,593 INFO  [streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-50] o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-50-restore-consumer, groupId=] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-09-09T16:06:43,593 INFO  [streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-50] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread: stream-thread [streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-50] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2019-09-09T16:06:43,593 INFO  [streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-50] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams: stream-client [streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
2019-09-09T16:11:39,386 INFO  [kafka-producer-network-thread | b2b] o.a.k.c.Metadata: Cluster ID: O8kYaORIQQ2vie_DUA_xvA
2019-09-09T16:11:41,148 INFO  [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.a.ConfigClusterResolver: Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-09-09T16:11:41,624 INFO  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-1-producer] o.a.k.c.Metadata: Cluster ID: O8kYaORIQQ2vie_DUA_xvA
2019-09-09T16:11:41,672 INFO  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-userstream-76ccdde0-115e-489e-894f-ec88aa9e3e2d-StreamThread-2-producer] o.a.k.c.Metadata: Cluster ID: O8kYaORIQQ2vie_DUA_xvA
```

I deleted my application id in  **/tmp/kafka/stat** but still not receiving.

But below kafka consumer client gets the data when I test

```
/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server serverip:9237 --from-beginning --topic usertopic
```

Comment: Check is there any lag for your application with kafka-tool: `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka_addres:port --group streams-userstream --describe`

Comment: You should definitely allow your Kafka Streams application to shutdown gracefuly.    `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));`

Comment: Does this shutdown will work even the process is killed using kill command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be running other consumer instance of same group, for testing purpose you can change stream groupname

```
 props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-userstream");

 change to 

 props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-userstream-test");
```

if this works then it should be any of the below reasons

```
1. Other instance is running with same group name 
2. Your stream is not gracefully shutdown 
3. your state dir is not cleaned
```